# Passive voice in (object) relative clause with infinitive sub-clause: "...that you would like to be mentioned."

Tags: passive-voice, relative-clauses

I was writing this sentence and then it occurred to me that it probably isn't right and might be a case of a dangling modifier:

*Is there any topic [that] you would like (to?) be mentioned here?*

With or without the *to*, this sentence doesn't sound correct... or is it?
Obviously (I hope!) the intended meaning, phrased as a statement instead of a question, is: *I would like the following topic to be mentioned here:...*

I'll be rephrasing the sentence, so this is more of an academic question concerning the boundaries of relative clause enthusiasm than a request for help expressing what I mean here.

Comment: What do you want mentioned?

Comment: Remove both the the *to* ***and*** the *be*: *Is there any topic you would like mentioned here?* There's no reason for the infinitive, bare or otherwise.